# tabs not working after upgrading from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.8.2

Tags: jquery

Really simple code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
</script>
```

Stops working after upgrading from 1.4.1 to 1.8 jquery. Any help?

Comment: you also have to upgrade jquery UI Tab

Comment: Please put the html code you are using in the question. Also, have you tried the code here http://jqueryui.com/tabs/. Is it working for you?